# Multiple arguments for script

Tags: linux, shell-script

I am trying to setup the script below to take multiple argument input on the command line. I am using the script to request ssl certs from letsencrypt. The script currently takes one domain at a time but I would like to be able to set it to accept multiple command line arguments so that I will be able to use it to request for certs for domains that have multiple alternate names(example: domain.com and www.domain.com) I have tried changing `CERTNAME="${2}"` to `CERTNAME="$@"` and `CERTNAME=$(echo "${2}" | sed -n "s/.*'\([^']\+\)'.*/\1/p")` to `CERTNAME=$(echo "$@" | sed -n "s/.*'\([^']\+\)'.*/\1/p")` but it keeps getting stuck at `echo "error: wrong CERTTYPE"`. I run the script like so `./<script name> --issue c_domain.com_rsa` and it works but as soon as I add another argument like so `./<script name> --issue c_domain.com_rsa c_www.domain.com_rsa` it doesn't work. What I'm I doing wrong? Script is below:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" = "--issue" ]; then
  CERTNAME="${2}"

else
  CERTNAME=$(echo "${2}" | sed -n "s/.*'\([^']\+\)'.*/\1/p")

fi
  CERTFILE=$(echo "${CERTNAME}" | cut -d'_' -f 2)
  CERTTYPE=$(echo "${CERTNAME}" | cut -d'_' -f 3)

if [ -z "$CERTNAME" ] || [ -z "$CERTFILE" ] || [ -z "$CERTTYPE" ]; then
  echo "error, can't figure out CERTNAME or CERTFILE or CERTTYPE"
  exit 1
fi

ZCLI=$(locate zcli 2>/dev/null | egrep "test/bin/zcli$")
[ -z "$ZCLI" ] && ZCLI=$(which zcli)
[ -z "$ZCLI" ] && ZCLI=$(find / -name zcli | egrep "test/bin/zcli$")

if [ -z "$ZCLI" ]; then
  echo "Can't find zcli command"
  exit 1
fi


ACMEHOME="/root/certs/"
ACMEOPTIONS="--standalone --httpport 88"
TEST="--test --days 0"

case "$CERTTYPE" in
  ecc)
    ACMEKEY="--keylength ec-256"
    CERTDIR=$ACMEHOME/${CERTFILE}_${CERTTYPE}
    ;;
  rsa)
    ACMEKEY="--keylength 2048"
    CERTDIR=$ACMEHOME/${CERTFILE}
    ;;
  *)
   echo "error: wrong CERTTYPE"
   exit 1
esac

 if [ -d $CERTDIR ]; then
   # certificate renewal
   ACMEACTION="--renew"
   if [ "$CERTTYPE" = "ecc" ]; then
     ACMEKEY="--ecc"
   fi
else
  # certificate issuance
  ACMEACTION="--issue"
fi

$ACMEHOME/acme.sh $TEST $ACMEOPTIONS $ACMEACTION -d ${CERTFILE} $ACMEKEY

# key
key=$(cat $CERTDIR/${CERTFILE}.key)
key=${key//$'\n'/\\n}

# crt
crt=$(cat $CERTDIR/fullchain.cer)
crt=${crt//$'\n'/\\n}

echo "Catalog.SSL.Certificates.setRawCertificate ${CERTNAME} \"$crt\" " > 
$CERTDIR/zcli_${CERTFILE}.script 
$ZCLI $CERTDIR/zcli_${CERTFILE}.script
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
echo "Catalog.SSL.Certificates.importCertificate ${CERTNAME} { private_key: 
\"$key\", public_cert: \"$crt\" }" > $CERTDIR/zcli_${CERTFILE}.script
$ZCLI $CERTDIR/zcli_${CERTFILE}.script
fi

echo "Done!"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's going on in the rest of your script, but you're not handling positional parameters correctly.  Setting `CERTNAME` to `$@` will set it to a string containing all of the parameters, including `--include`.  Then you're running `cut` on this string, which I'm not sure what you expect to do.  If you want to loop over parameters, you can do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ "$1" = "--issue" ]]; then
   certs=("${@:2}")
else
   :
   # something else here
fi

for cert in "${certs[@]}"; do
   echo "$cert"
   # process each cert here
done

exit
```

Given your last example this will print:

```
c_domain.com_rsa
c_www.domain.com_rsa
```

This puts all of your positional parameters excluding `$1` into an array and loops over it.  If you want to put the rest of the parameters into a string, just remove the parentheses like this: `certs="${@:2}"`

Using `$@` this way is a bit confusing: when you say `"$@"` it expands positional parameters into words, i.e. `$1`..`$n`.  However, using it in an array context like I'm doing will include `$0`, which is the name of the script.  That's why I'm starting the slice at element 2.

Like I said there's a lot of other things going on here, but this should answer the question about parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the example. I don't want it to loop over the arguments. I am trying to request a cert and what I am trying to achieve is request one cert for a domain but that domain has multiple alternate names so for example, instead of requesting a cert for ```domain.com``` and ```www.domain.com```(two seperate certs), I can just request a cert for ```domain.com```(with ```www.domain.com``` as alternate name), thus one cert but serves two domains.